# List network policy rules kube-proxy on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube, azure-aks

could you please help me? Where I can find list network policy rules kube-proxy on minikube?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what exactly you want to list ? If it comes to listing **network policies** in all your namespaces, you can use the following command:

```
kubectl get networkpolicies  --all-namespaces
```

If you want to list all your `kube-proxy` related resources, you can do it by running:

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces | grep kube-proxy
```

As you can see there are only `Pods` and they are located in `kube-system` namespace, so `kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system` will also list them.

If you want to see their details, run:

```
kubectl describe pod <kube-proxy-pod-name> -n kube-system
```

Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.